# I am unable to check with member is active or not

Tags: mailgun, elgg

How to check with member is active or not while sending a emails.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeout = 300; // timeout in 5min, 
$last_action = $user->last_action;

if (time() - $last_action < $timeout) {
//DO THE STUFF 
}
```

Comment: Please be careful when you're linking to a third-party site. [**I think you don't want to be a spammer**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). However, Martijin has removed the link from your answer, but **don't do that again** next time.